# How to find longest prefix from array list using given string value in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, prefix, longest-substring

```
String[] num = { "1201", "12018", "1201800","12018000" };

String prefix="120180000175135";
```

I have two variables one is String array and other one is String.
Now I want to get longest value from String array using prefix. Please suggest me how can I do it in Java.

Please review also my solution but it does not work in above condition.

```
private static Item binarySearch(Item[] a, String key) {
    int low = 0;
    System.out.println("a.length" + a.length);
    int high = a.length - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        int len = Math.min(key.length(), a[mid].key.length());
        String midVal = a[mid].key.substring(0, len);
        String cmpKey = key.substring(0, len);
        if (midVal.compareTo(cmpKey) > 0)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal.compareTo(cmpKey) < 0)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return a[mid];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array of numbers be sorted ascending by length, you could iterate backwards and use `String#startsWith`, printing the first match:

```
String[] num = { "1201", "12018", "1201800","12018000" };
String prefix = "120180000175135";

for (int i=num.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (prefix.startsWith(num[i])) {
        System.out.println("Longest match is: " + num[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

If the array of numbers is *not* already sorted, then you could either do a sort, or instead you would have to iterate the entire unsorted array and keep track of the length of each match.

Answer (score 0):

Or using stream:

```
String[] num = { "1201", "12018", "1201800","12018000" };
String prefix = "120180000175135";
    
Optional<String> match = Arrays.asList(num).stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed())
    .filter(prefix::startsWith)
    .findFirst();
System.out.println("Longest match is: " + match.orElse("no match found"));
```